# Get all rows with sum if not found set null - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models: `Employee` and `WorkingDay`.

```
//Employee Model

public function workingDays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(WorkingDay::class, 'employee_id','id');
    }

public function scopeTotalHours($query, $from, $to)
    {
        $query->whereHas('workingDays', function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
            $query->whereBetween('work_date', [$from, $to]);
        })->withSum('workingDays', 'hours_work');
    }
```

I want to receive sum of hours for each employee between specified date. But if employee doesnt exist in `working_days` table, set value to `0` or `null`

```
//Query

Employee::totalHours($week->start->toDateTimeString(), $week->end->toDateTimeString())->get()
```

What I get if `employee_id` doesnt exist in `working_days`:

```
items = []
```

But I want something like this:

```
Between: 2020-10-31 and 2020-11-05

items = [ 
 all employees with additional column: sum of hours
 Employee fields, 25 //exists
 Employee fields, 0 or null //doesnt exist
]
```

Is possible to do it using query builder?

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Is possible to do it with query builder?